# Can't find element in my template after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to find an image inside my template on the Success of an Ajax call... but I can't!

Here is my code:

```
class AvatarView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/twitter_avatar"]

  initialize:(options) ->
    @user = options.user

  render: =>
    @$el.html(@template({
      view_id: @cid
      avatar_url: @user.avatar() || "src/image_not_found.png"
    }))
    @$el.find(".avatar").on('error', @_reloadAvatar)

  _reloadAvatar: =>
    $.ajax
      type: 'GET'
      url: "/profiles/api/twitter/#{@user.social_network_id()}/avatar_url"
      success: (response) =>
        if response.success
          avatar_url = response.avatar_url
        else
          avatar_url = 'https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png'
        @$el.find(".avatar").attr('src', avatar_url)  # Here is the problem
```

When I debug this:

- "this" is an instance of AvatarView and
- @$el is an empty div, and can't find avatar class.

Here is the template:

```
<img src="<%= avatar_url %>" alt="avatar" class="avatar" id="avatar-image-<%= view_id %>">
```

I fell like I'm loosing my DOM object or something like that..

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening but what happens when you make the `onerror` callback actually change the user's avatar and call the render function again?

Answer (score 0):

I still not understanding why it doesn't work, but I solved my problem using the event parameter:

```
_reloadAvatar:(event) =>
$.ajax
  type: 'GET'
  url: "/profiles/api/twitter/#{@user.social_network_id()}/avatar_url"
  success: (response) =>
    if response.success
      avatar_url = response.avatar_url
    else
      avatar_url = 'https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png'
    @(event.target).attr('src', avatar_url)
```